# WP7 updating bing map as you scroll along

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I use an iphone app which displays points on a map from an api depending on the maps location, when you move the map, the map updates and re-queries the api after a couple of seconds. How would I achieve this 'detect map centre change' on bing maps and WP7?

Many thanks.
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bing Maps control exposes `ViewChangeStart` and `ViewChangeEnd` which can be used to detect the start and end of a change in view. You can subscribe to these events, get the current view and query your API accordingly.

See the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.viewchangeend.aspx